# After update to Angular12 i18n localizing dosnt work anymore

Tags: internationalization, translation, angular12

I updated the source code of my app from Angular6 to Angular12 - yes, I missed it to update it more often.

Now the IU language is not changing anymore. I am using i18n. It seems like the html is not applying the translation. Because I can still load the XLF file from the API, but the translations are not shown in the UI.

In the Angular app I have to following code in my main.ts:

```js
const httpClient: HttpClient = injector.get(HttpClient);
httpClient.get(localizationUrl, {responseType: "text"})
    .subscribe(res => {
            const translations = res;
            let locale = "de-DE";
            let respCulture = /(?:(?:target-language)="([\w-]+)")/i.exec(translations);
            if (respCulture)
                locale = respCulture[1];
            platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
                // missingTranslation: MissingTranslationStrategy.Warning,
                providers: [
                    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: locale},
                    {provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations},
                    {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: "xlf"}
                ]
            });
        },
        error => console.log(error));
```

The locale was always "de", I also tried "de-DE" but it does not change the behavior.
In my html I am using the i18n like this:

```html
<h3 i18n="@@settings-tab-header">You will receive your incoming invoices automatically in PDF format.</h3>
```

I tried to find a problem, comparing my code to https://angular.io/guide/i18n , but I cant find anything.
Also I tried to comment the "provide: LOCALE_ID.." and "provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT.." but it did not help me.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now by providing the translations in the app. Therefore I lost the benefit of changing the translations without app deployment.